# jQuery div animations buggy on first instance

Tags: jquery, animation

I am having issues with jQuery animations on a really simple slider. The first time you click on them the animation seems buggy. The animations make the divs break the container. I add overflow: hidden to the containing div, but it just makes the content 'flash' instead of overflow underneath.

After the first click of each element, the animations are fine. Any idea how to avoid this behaviour?

Here is the example: http://jsbin.com/izuviv/edit#preview

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="slide expanded">
        <img />
        <a href="">
            <h3>Lorem</h3>
            <p>Ipsum</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img />
        <a href="">
            <h3>Lorem</h3>
            <p>Ipsum</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img />
        <a href="">
            <h3>Lorem</h3>
            <p>Ipsum</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide last">
        <img />
        <a href="">
            <h3>Lorem</h3>
            <p>Ipsum</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slider {width: 632px; height: 231px; margin: 100px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
    #slider .slide {width: 71px; height: 231px; background: black; margin: 0 4px 0 0; float: left; display: inline; position: relative;}
        #slider .slide a {display: block; width: 71px; height: 72px; background: transparent url(../img/white.png) 0 0 repeat; text-decoration: none; color: #000; position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
        #slider .slide h3 {display: none;}
        #slider .slide p {display: none;}

    #slider .last {margin: 0;}
    #slider .expanded {width: 407px;}
        #slider .expanded a {width: 407px; background: transparent url(../img/white.png) 0 0 repeat;}
        #slider .expanded h3 {margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; display: block;}
        #slider .expanded p {margin: 5px 10px; font-size: 12px; display: inline;}
```

JS

```
function slider() { 

    var slide = $('#slider div');

    slide.click(function(){

        var expanded = $('#slider .expanded');

        if (!$(this).hasClass('expanded') ) {

            // 1: Shrink expanded div
            expanded.animate({
                width: '71px'
            }, 200, function() {
                console.log('contract');
                // 2: Remove expanded class
                $(this).removeClass('expanded');
            });

            // 3: Add expanded class to clicked
            $(this).addClass('expanded');

            // 4: Expand clicked div
            $(this).animate({
                width: '407px'
            }, 200, function() {
                console.log('expand');
            });

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MoinZaman I have added the jsbin example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Function Slider, i changed the code into:

```
$('.slide').click(function (){
    $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('expanded')){
      $exp = $('.expanded');
      $exp.animate({width:'71px'},200,function (){$exp.removeClass('expanded');});
      $this.animate({width:'407px'},200).addClass('expanded');
    }
});
```

Now, it works fine..
I think what cause the problem is: $(this);.. Always save **this** into a variable to prevent errors and duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As I observed and try your code, It is buggy first time, because all div are not having their inline width, you are setting the width of a tag in slider class. but If you set the width for div then it will not cause any buggy behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your slide() function as below

```
function slider() { 

    var slide = $('#slider div');

    slide.click(function(){

        var expanded = $('#slider .expanded');

        if (!$(this).hasClass('expanded') ) {

            // 1: Shrink expanded div
            expanded.animate({
                width: '71px'
            }, 200, function() {
                console.log('contract');
                // 2: Remove expanded class
                $(this).removeClass('expanded');
            });

            // 3: Add expanded class to clicked
            //$(this).addClass('expanded');

            // 4: Expand clicked div
            $(this).animate({
                width: '407px'
            }, 200, function() {
                console.log('expand');
                $(this).addClass('expanded');
            });

        }

    });
}
```

I have just added code related to adding class inside animate complete